# Change a value in a file and run all tests again

Tags: nunit, integration-testing

I wrote an integration test suite using NUnit. Since we're talking integration tests, test code uses configuration files, the file system, database and so on.

However, I noticed that it would be nice to change the test environment (i.e. change a value inside a configuration file - this would change the code behavior in some cases), and then run the full test suite again but using this new environment.

Is there a way to automate this using NUnit? I have code that updates the file, so if I can somehow set things up programatically, great.

Comment: As I understand changing file values to prepare new config is not recommended in unit tests. If i were you i'd try to use smth like an array of pathes to files which include different configs (file per config). nevertheless is the question actual?

Comment: These are not unit tests, these are integration tests. The most sensible solution I thought of would be similar to what you proposed;  I would use NUnit's Parameterized Tests concept to run the tests againt a set of paths. Problem is, I'd need to rewrite all tests and this a big suite. I'm currently looking into doing it with a regex replace. So I guess it's not actual since I found a solution and I'm facing another issue now, but I'll leave it open in case someone knows of a smarter way.